# Need Child Account Trigger Help

Tags: apex, trigger, account, field-update, update

I am trying to update all child accounts to have the same Order Manager(lookup to Contact) as their parent.
The caveat is that I only want to do this for accounts that arent parented by my two top level accounts in the hierarchy.
What am I doing wrong?

```
trigger Child_Updates on Account (after update) {
   If(Trigger.isUpdate){

     Set<ID> ids = Trigger.newMap.keySet();
     list<Account> updatedParents = [SELECT Id, Order_Manager__c, ParentId, 
                 (SELECT Id, Order_Manager__c, ParentId 
                  from ChildAccounts ) FROM Account
                 WHERE Id in :ids];
         List<Account> childrenToUpdate = new List<Account>();

         //Then loop through each parent object in 'updated parent
         for ( Account  p : updatedParents) 
         { 
        if(p.ParentId != '001170000089QGbAAM' || '001170000089QGg'){

                //and loop thru each kid in the child set}
               for(Account kid : p.ChildAccounts) 
               { 
                         ///update logic from above
                          if(kid.Order_Manager__c != p.Order_Manager__c)
{
       kid.Order_Manager__c =  p.Order_Manager__c;
      childrenToUpdate.add(kid);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you populating childaccounts?

Comment: i don't know. im fairly new to development and have gone in circles here trying to get this to work.

Comment: change this to if(p.ParentId != '001170000089QGbAAM' || p.ParentId !='001170000089QGg')

Comment: NEVER HARD CODE IDS! When you want specific records like that, you should query for them using a unique identifier.

Answer (score 0):

First off, there's an issue that I see with your initial query:

```
list<Account> updatedParents = [SELECT Id, Order_Manager__c, ParentId, 
             (SELECT Id, Order_Manager__c, ParentId 
              from ChildAccounts ) 
              FROM Account WHERE Id in :ids];
```

When you do a subquery like this, you can't query the ParentId of the Child Accounts, because the primary Id in the query is already the parent that it's related to. At least none of the tools I have would allow me to select ParentId in this kind of subquery.

Next, in order to retrieve these, you'd want to make your query results return to a Map, not a list. Having them in a map will make the results of the subquery much easier to retrieve from the query results.

That having been said, do you only want to update children as they appear or do you want to update children at any time either their parent or the actual account appears?

If the former, this becomes simpler because you can forgo the subquery and will only need to look for accounts which have a parent account. Otherwise, you'll need to sort the map which is returned from the query to get a list of the related child accounts for each parent.

If you do the latter, your trigger would something like this:

**Edit:** Revised code

```
trigger Child_Updates on Account (after update) {
   If(Trigger.isUpdate)
   {

     Set<ID> ids = Trigger.newMap.keySet();
     map<Id,Account> mapAccts2Up = new map([SELECT Id, Order_Manager__c, ParentId 
                  FROM Account
                 WHERE Id in :ids ]);


         //Then loop through each Accct to discover it in Master Account and whether it's a child or a Parent Acct.

         set<Id>prntIds = new set<Id>();
         set<Id>prntPIds = new set<Id>();
         set<Id>childIds = new set<Id>();
         map<Id,Id>prnt2child = new map<Id,Id>();
         map<Id,Id>chld2prnt = new map<Id,Id>();

         set<Id>AcountIds = new set<Id>();
         AccountIds = mapAccts2Up.keyset();

         for ( Id pId : AccountIds) 
         { 

            try{
                if((mapAccts2Up.get(pId).ParentId) == null){ 
                    parentIds.add(pId);
                }else{ 
                    childIds.add(pId);
                }                  
            }catch{ nullpointerexception(e);
                prntIds.add(pId);
            }

            if((pId != '001170000089QGbAAM' || pId != '001170000089QGg') && prntIds.contains(pId))
            {

                prntPIds.add(pId);


            }else if((mapAccts2Up.get(pId).ParentId != '001170000089QGbAAM' || mapAccts2Up.get(pId).ParentId != '001170000089QGg') && prntIds.contains(pId) == false && childIds.contains(pId) == true )
            {

                prnt2child.put(mapAccts2Up.get(pId).ParentId,pId);
                chld2prnt.put(pId,mapAccts2Up.get(pId).ParentId);
            }
        }


        //and loop thru each kid in the child set

        for(Id cid : childIds) 
        { 
                  //update logic from above
            if(Accts2Update.get(cid).Order_Manager__c != Accts2Update.get(cid).Order_Manager__c)
            {
                Accts2Update.get(cid).Order_Manager__c = Accts2Update.get(cid).Order_Manager__c;
                childrenToUpdate.add(Accts2Update.get(cid));
            }
        }

        update childrenToUpdate;
    }

}
```

If you do the former, you'll need to use a query that will look like this:

**Edit:** Revised code

```
map<Id,Account> mapAccts2Up = new map([SELECT Id, Order_Manager__c, ParentId
    (SELECT Id, Order_Manager__c from ChildAccounts) 
          FROM Account WHERE Id in :ids ]);


list<Account> Paccts = new list<Account>();
list<Account> Caccts = new list<Account>();
list<Account> Prntaccts = new list<Account>();
list<Account> Chldaccts = new list<Account>();


AccountIds = mapAccts2Up.keyset();
map<Account,Account>c2p = new map<Account,Account>();
        for (Id AccountId : AccountIds) 
        {

            /* use loops to retrieve lists of Parent and Child Accounts */

            Account acct = mapAccts2Up.get(AccountId);

            Caccts = acct.ChildAccts;

            // filter base accts into parent and child accounts
            if(acct.ParentID != null)
            {
                account act = new account(Id = act.ParentID);
                Prntaccts.add(act);
                Chldaccts.add(acct);
                c2pmap.put(acct,act);
            }else if(acct.ParentID == null)
            {
                Prntaccts.add(acct)
            }


            For(account ac: Caccts){
                if(ac.ParentID != null)
                {
                    account ap = new account(Id = ac.ParentID);
                    Prntaccts.add(ap);
                    Chldaccts.add(ac);
                    c2pmap.put(ac,ap);
                }else if(ac.ParentID == null)
                {
                    Prntaccts.add(ac)
                }

                if(ac.ChildAccount.Id != null)
                {
                    account ac = new account(Id = acct.ChildAccount.Id);
                    Chldaccts.add(ac);
                    c2pmap.put(ac,acct);
                }
            }

        }
```

**Note:** none of the above code has been tested or debugged. It is provided "as is" with the intent to illustrate the principles. It's up to you to do any debugging and add try-catch blocks as needed to trap null pointer exceptions.

Comment: Note: I found an error in my code where two of the loops needed separated in the final section of code with a minor tweak in the 1st section, both of which I've corrected in what's above.