# Create Visualforce PageBlockTable Showing Aggregated Data from Multiple Objects

Tags: visualforce

Is it possible to create a visualforce PageBlockTable that has a row for each user, and each row contains an integer for the total number of accounts and leads owned by that user? It needs to be one table, nested tables won’t accomplish it.

So you have three objects: User, Account, Lead. Pretty simple.

The table would look something like below:

[image]

Update: I discovered how to do this with a wrapper class! This particular task cannot be accomplished with the aggregate function and query that is suggested below, because of the polymorphic nature of the Owner field on Account and Lead. But it can be accomplished using the code the below. If this question gets taken off hold, I can also post the full controller and VF page!

```
public class UserWrapper{  //wrapper upon which VF may iterate  

   //declare variable for each VF column 
   public User Owner { get; set; }
   public Integer OppsOwned { get; set; }
   public Integer LeadsOwned { get; set; }
   public Date MaxDate { get; set; }
   public Decimal ConvRate { get; set; }
   public Decimal TotalValOpps { get; set; }

   //create an instance of class to which to pass values from controller 
   public UserWrapper(User Owner1, Integer LeadsOwned1, Integer OppsOwned1, 
                      Decimal ConvRate1, Date MaxDate1, Decimal TotalValOpps1 ) { 
      Owner = Owner1;
      LeadsOwned = LeadsOwned1; 
      OppsOwned = OppsOwned1; 
      ConvRate = ConvRate1; ConvRate = ConvRate.setScale(0);                    
      MaxDate = MaxDate1;
      TotalValOpps = TotalValOpps1;                      
   }
```

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: This has been updated, and is pretty clear - I have the whole solution now, how can this be unclosed so that the solution can be posted?

Comment: Still waiting to get this re-opened...SSE? Hello?

Comment: I just nominated this for re-opening since you've accepted my answer.

Comment: @crmprogdev thanks, yes it's pretty clear and I have the full code for this specific example that could help a lot of people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Since you're putting them all in one table with the same header. I'd expect you'd be able to write this as a single query and order by UserId. See the [SOQL and SOSL Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_sosl_intro.htm) for help on writing the query.

If you can't get the results in one query you'll want to create a custom controller class that assembles the results of your separate queries ordered by user. Once you do that, it's pretty straightforward to put it into a table and iterate on it just as you would the results of any other query in a table. Just declare the combined "wrapper" separately and use a method to assemble the wrapper and you'll have all you need once you have your query results.

**EDIT**

The data model is illustrated in an ERD shown on the [Sales Object page of the SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_majors.htm). A query for everything except leads would look something like the following:

```
list<Id>UserIds = new list<id>; // List of the users you want to include
map<Id,string>idToUserName = new map<id,string>(); // to hold usernames you'll need

list<aggregateResult>userAccountRel = new list<aggregateResult>();

userAccountRel = [SELECT Count(Id), (SELECT Count(), ContactId, OwnerId 
                    FROM Opportunity) FROM Account WHERE OwnerId IN UserIds
                         ORDER BY OwnerId];
```

You now have a list of Accounts, a count of Opportunities, the contactId associated with each opportunity (if one exists), and the OwnerId of each Account and each Opportunity. I purposely didn't add OwnerId to the Account select portion of the query since in many orgs, Opportunities are owned by someone other than the Account owner.

If you have Opportunities that aren't associated with an Account, then "Houston, we have a problem" in this Org! It means you're creating Opportunities without associating them with an Account and haven't converted your qualified lead to a Contact. Each company's process will be different and I understand that. However, I don't know how to create an Opportunity that's not associated with an Account. Leads can also be Contacts. Leads ultimately get either deleted or converted.

If you find yourself in the situation where you need to report something on Leads, you'd then define a wrapper class to hold the results of your query on leads owned by your users.

The class would look something like this:

```
public class OwnedObjectRecords {
    public list<aggregrateResult>userAccountRel {get; set;}
    public list<aggregateReslt>userLeadRel{get; set;}

    public list OwnedObjectRecords(list<aggregateResult> a, list<aggregateResult> b) {
        UserAccountRel = a;
        userLeadRel = b;
        // you'll need to do some processing to combine these lists
    }
}
```

If you need to do the above, if it were me, I'd break out your lists beforehand for each object (Opportunity(count), Account(count), list Contact, etc by OwnerId) and then pass them into your wrapper (defined differently). That will make the wrapper easier to assemble, process and iterate on.

If not, I'd think you'll essentially need to do that within the wrapper when you combine the two lists. It's been a while since I've done this kind of thing. Others might have a more efficient suggestion on how to code it, but that would definitely get the job done for you.

**EDIT 2**

I found an answer of mine that illustrates the techniques you're looking for to break out the subqueries so you can get the count of Accounts, Opportunities and a list of Contacts if needed and map them to the OwnerId (UserId).

You'll want to do something similar to [Need Child Account Trigger Help](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/69235/need-child-account-trigger-help/69262#69262). In most of these situations, you'll still be creating list that includes count() and OwnerId that you'll need to keep track of. That should point you in the right direction.

You'll want to do this because you can't just add one list to another even though they're both of type aggregateResult. Based on your brief example, you might need to separate your results by any of the following as relates to the OwnerId: Accounts, count(Opportunities) per Account, count(Opportunities) per UserId, Contact by Opportunity, list by UserId plus count(Opportunity??) on Lead. As you've not shared how you're creating Opportunities from Leads, I can't tell you how to create that query.

I'm sharing a pattern here, not just a single use case specific to your post. If you have a count() of "something" on the Lead object, you'd want to add it to the wrapper class list separately associated with the OwnerId. That's why you'd want to break these out into two or more list items and likely create maps so you can later extract them, especially if your table is going to include additional counts or relationships with other objects.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how one can write a single query that returns three unrelated objects (Owner is polymorphic and unhelpful). Could you provide an example? Don't see any in the SOQL Reference. And how would one "assemble" the results of three separate queries in a way that a table could reference?

Comment: The Owner is the common link for sorting and all except Lead are related to Account. Correct? If you don't follow all of that, you'll want to look at the [Sales Objects Data Model in the SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_majors.htm) to see the relationships. I'll try to give you and example of combining the queries.

Comment: Sadly no, Owner only allows you to query child-to-parent, not the other way around. If you look at the data model there is no child relationship name for User to Lead, because the Owner field is polymorphic and can reference User or Queue. If you see a way around that would love to see. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, yes that would work if we needed just Accounts/Opportunities, but we don't, we need Leads too. I see where you are going, which is what I was thinking too, but we don't know how to do that "some processing" you mentioned. How can one combine the results of separate queries, in a way that a visualforce table can read it?

Comment: In essence, you're telling me you don't know how to separate out sub-queries from a query. I know there are numerous answers to that here on the board. I think I asked that question myself years ago when I first joined here. Let me see if I can find a link. That's the essence of what you'll need to do.

Comment: Okay, I found an answer of mine that illustrates the techniques you're looking for. You'll want to do something similar to https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/69235/need-child-account-trigger-help/69262#69262. In most of these situations, you'll still be creating lists of aggregrateResults for count, OwnerId that you'll need to keep track of. That should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Well, no, I'm not sure why we would separate out sub-queries, we're trying to combine queries (in essence). I think that's what they've been telling you. There is no sub-query to do because of the Owner field issue I've been mentioning. Will take a look though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the actual and complete answer with all code! Could have been sooner if other folks hadn't closed the question!

```
<apex:page controller="UserLeadsAndOppsController" >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="User Leads and Opps" id="contacts_list">           
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!UserWrappers}" var="uw">          
                <apex:column value="{! uw.Owner.Name }">
                    <apex:facet name="header">Owner</apex:facet>
                    </apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{! uw.LeadsOwned }">
                    <apex:facet name="header">Total Leads</apex:facet>
                    </apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{! uw.OppsOwned }">
                    <apex:facet name="header">Total Opps</apex:facet>
                    </apex:column>
                <apex:column value="{! uw.ConvRate }%">
                    <apex:facet name="header">Conv Rate</apex:facet>
                    </apex:column> 
                <apex:column headerValue="Max Created Date (Opp)" >
                     <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM/dd/yyyy}">
                           <apex:param value="{!uw.MaxDate}" />
                     </apex:outputText>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Total Val (Opp)" >
                     <apex:outputText value="{0,Number,Currency}">
                           <apex:param value="{!uw.TotalValOpps}" />
                     </apex:outputText>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class UserLeadsAndOppsController { 

   //query relevant data from all 3 objects - User, Oppo, and Lead
   public User[] getUsers() { 
      return [select Name, Id from User WHERE NAME != 'Automated Process' ]; 
   }  
   public Opportunity[] getOppos() { 
      return [select Name, Id, OwnerId, CreatedDate, Amount from Opportunity]; 
   }
   public Lead[] getLeads() { 
      return [select Name, Id, OwnerId from Lead]; 
   }

   //create method to perform calculations and send result to wrapper class
   public UserLeadsAndOppsWrapper[] getUserWrappers(){

      UserLeadsAndOppsWrapper[] result = new List <UserLeadsAndOppsWrapper>(); 

      //grab lists we already queried
      User[] allUsers = getUsers(); 
      Opportunity[] allOppos = getOppos(); 
      Lead[] allLeas = getLeads(); 

      //create outer loop on user since our chart iterates users 
      for(User U: allUsers) { 

         //declare oppo variables for number of opps owner, most recent created date, and total value of opps        
         Integer OpposOwned = 0;
         Date MaxDate = Date.newInstance(1900, 12, 31); 
         Decimal TotalValOpps = 0.00;

         //create inner loop on Oppo since we're counting/summing them for each user 
         for(Opportunity O: allOppos){ 
            if(O.OwnerId == U.id){ //make sure Opp belongs to the user whose loop we are in
               OpposOwned++; //increment # of oppos owned by user

               TotalValOpps = TotalValOpps + O.Amount; //add Amount to total for user

               if(O.CreatedDate.date() > MaxDate){ //compare created date against others, and if most recent, update variable
                  MaxDate = O.CreatedDate.date(); 
               }
            }
         }
         if(MaxDate == Date.newInstance(1900, 12, 31)){
              MaxDate=null;  //if no opps found, null out the recent date variable so no date shows
         }

         //declare lead variable      
         Integer LeadsOwned = 0;
         //create another inner loop on lead since we're counting them for each user 
         for(Lead L: allLeas) { 
            if(L.OwnerId == u.id){ 
                LeadsOwned++; //increment # of leads owned by user
            } 
         }

         Decimal ConvRate= 0; //calculate conv rate
            if(LeadsOwned != 0){ //dividing by 0 is fun theoretically, bad otherwise
                ConvRate = ((Double) OpposOwned)/LeadsOwned*100;
            }

         //check that user has some records, then add user and all data to the result list
         if(OpposOwned != 0 || LeadsOwned != 0){
           result.add(new UserLeadsAndOppsWrapper(U, LeadsOwned, OpposOwned, ConvRate, MaxDate, TotalValOpps));
         }   
      }

   return result; 
}
}
```

Wrapper:

```
public class UserLeadsAndOppsWrapper{  //wrapper upon which VF may iterate  

   //declare variable for each VF column 
   public User Owner { get; set; }
   public Integer OppsOwned { get; set; }
   public Integer LeadsOwned { get; set; }
   public Date MaxDate { get; set; }
   public Decimal ConvRate { get; set; }
   public Decimal TotalValOpps { get; set; }

   //create an instance of class to which to pass values from controller 
   public UserLeadsAndOppsWrapper(User Owner1, Integer LeadsOwned1, Integer OppsOwned1, 
                      Decimal ConvRate1, Date MaxDate1, Decimal TotalValOpps1 ) { 
      Owner = Owner1;
      LeadsOwned = LeadsOwned1; 
      OppsOwned = OppsOwned1; 
      ConvRate = ConvRate1; ConvRate = ConvRate.setScale(0);                    
      MaxDate = MaxDate1;
      TotalValOpps = TotalValOpps1;                      
   } 
}
```